# White line flash on UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a simple `UIDatePicker` attached to one of the cells on my Settings screen. When it presents a white line flashes on it's top border for a second then goes away.

All views on this screen have a black background.

I also have a separate `UIPickerView` on this screen and it has the same issue.

I can't take a screenshot as it's so quick. Anyone run into this issue??

---

Here's my code for both the `UIDatePicker` and the `UIPickerView` -- right now this is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where I set each picker as the `inputView` of a `UITextView` in each cell:

```
  // -- create and set gender picker view
    if (indexPath.row == SettingsRow.Gender.rawValue) {
        let genderTextField = cell.rightTextField
        genderTextField.delegate = self
        let genderPicker = UIPickerView()
        genderPicker.accessibilityLabel = "gender_picker"
        genderPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        genderPicker.delegate = self
        genderPicker.dataSource = self           
        genderTextField.inputView = genderPicker
    }


    // -- create and set birthday picker view
    if (indexPath.row == SettingsRow.Birthday.rawValue) {
        let birthDateTextField = cell.rightTextField
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.accessibilityLabel = "date_of_birth_picker"
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingsUserProfileViewController.onDatePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        let eighteenYears:NSTimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 18
        datePicker.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -eighteenYears)
        datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
        birthDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
    }
```

Comment: How are you "presenting" the date picker?

Comment: can you add some code or something to work with?

Comment: @MarcusAdams It's the `inputView` of a `UITextView` that's added to one of the cells

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've added the code for how I create each picker

Comment: Same code. Doesn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this stupid problem. I just added a two point high line to the the of the picker, which covers the flash. Still have no idea why it's there. I ran a loop to hide all the subviews of the picker, and it was still there. So it has something to do with the view the picker is presented in, but I don't know what that is.

```
func setupGenderPicker() -> UIPickerView {
    let genderPicker = UIPickerView()
    genderPicker.accessibilityLabel = "gender_picker"
    genderPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    genderPicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
    genderPicker.delegate = self
    genderPicker.dataSource = self
    genderPicker.selectRow(VMUserFacade.sharedInstance().currentUser.gender.integerValue, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

    // -- (this line covers up a white flash -- something to do with keyboard maybe? it's not one of the picker subviews)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 2.0)
    let line = UIView(frame: rect)
    line.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    genderPicker.addSubview(line)

    return genderPicker
}
```